# Notification custom Sound not playing UWP

Tags: c#, windows, notifications, uwp

I have tested my App without any custom sound and the default sound plays perfectly

```
var prayerName = App_Code.helperMethods.getPrayerNameforNotification(i);
        ToastAudio tA = new ToastAudio();
        tA.Src = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/AnyDay.mp3");


        ToastContent con = new ToastContent()
        {
            Visual = new ToastVisual()
            {
                TitleText = new ToastText() { Text = "Namaz Pro" },
                BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText() { Text = prayerName + " in " + App_Code.StoreRetrieveSettingsAssist.getLocation() },
                BodyTextLine2 = new ToastText() { Text = App_Code.helperMethods.userSpecifiedTimeFormat(myPT, DateTime.Today) },
            },

            Launch = DateTime.Today.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + i.ToString(),

            Scenario = ToastScenario.Alarm,

            Duration = ToastDuration.Short,

            Audio = tA,



        };



        return con;
```

I have three projects in my Solution :

- App_Code
- BackgroundTasks (References App_Code)
- Namaz Pro(References App_Code)  {MAIN APP}

My custom sound is "AnyDay.mp3"(for the curious ones its by Elvis) placed inside App_Code Project as : App_Code/Sounds/AnyDay.mp3

The code within which my above mentioned block is also within App_Code.

However the sound doesn't play at all and Notification acts as if it is silent.
I even tried a .wav file but still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your custom sound is inside App_Code Project as: ***App_Code/Sounds/AnyDay.mp3***, then you need use this URI:

```
ms-appx:///App_Code/Sounds/AnyDay.mp3
```

instead of `ms-appx:///Sounds/AnyDay.mp3`.

> While using the `ms-appx:` scheme, Windows Runtime APIs do not support URIs of type `UriKind.Relative`, so you typically use the signature that infers the UriKind and make sure you've specified a valid **absolute URI** including the scheme and authority.

To access files stored in a framework or library package that's included with the app, we can use an absolute URI like:

```
ms-appx:///App_Code/Sounds/AnyDay.mp3
```

If we use `ms-appx:///Sounds/AnyDay.mp3`, then the toast notification will use "*AnyDay.mp3*" under "*Namaz Pro/Sounds*", but as there is no such resource, the toast notification will act as silent.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. the custom  notification sound plays only on W10 Mobile. However it plays only for a few seconds(even for toastduration.long). How can I make it stay even longer till my 2min song completes?

Comment: Yeah, custom audio is only supported in Mobile. If you want to play it for a long time, you can try to remove the `Duration` and set `Scenario` to `Reminder` or `Alarm`.  `Duration` is not recommend in Windows 10. This attribute exists mainly for appCompat reason. As I tested in Mobile Emulator, the custom audio can play over 2 minutes.

Comment: Any workaround for getting it to work on PC ! The song is nearly 3 minutes ! It's a UWP app ! Will the custom notification sound play on tablet and other devices. What should I check to know the device supports custom notification ?

Comment: Only Mobile can use custom audio by now. You may try to use `Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily` to check whether the device supports custom audio, if it's value is `Windows.Mobile` then the device supports custom audio. But this is only a workaround as this property is intended for analytics use only.

Comment: Note that as of the Windows 10 November update (build 10586), Windows 10 on the desktop supports custom notification sounds with the following caveat: "...the custom toast audio will only work if your app is installed via the Store." Apparently this is fixed in the Anniversary update (build 14939).

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/06/18/quickstart-sending-a-toast-notification-with-custom-audio/

Answer (score 0):

There Could be some Reasons

- Make sure the audio File is in .WAV .WMA .MP3 Format
- Make sure the audio File duration is less than 10 seconds
- Make sure the audio File is stored in Application Directory or in Local Storage folder

  further more you can visit here [TOASTS for Windows Phone....](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_gdr3)